# How can I measure the similarity between 2 strings?

Tags: c#, string, comparison, phonetics

Given two strings `text1` and `text2`:

```
public SOMEUSABLERETURNTYPE Compare(string text1, string text2)
{
     // DO SOMETHING HERE TO COMPARE
}
```

Examples:

1. First String: StackOverflow

   Second String: StaqOverflow

   Return: Similarity is 91%

   The return can be in % or something like that.
2. First String: The simple text test

   Second String: The complex text test

   Return: The values can be considered equal

Any ideas? What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Why do you think the two strings in example 2 should compare equal?

Comment: Am I missing something here?  Did the original poster give any indication that he was concerned with phonetics, rather than the characters, other than the fact that the first example could be seen to imply phonetic similarity?  The second example certainly does not.

Comment: I guess that "Similarity" and "Phonetic" are closest, but are different things. The "Similarity" validation needs to use a "Phonetic" algorithm and "Similarity" algorithm to validate correctly a text.

Comment: @kcrumley: The second example is only hypothetical. Strings with some similarity for each found word, can be considered similar.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There are various different ways of doing this. Have a look at the [Wikipedia "String similarity measures" page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:String_similarity_measures) for links to other pages with algorithms.

I don't *think* any of those algorithms take sounds into consideration, however - so "staq overflow" would be as similar to "stack overflow" as "staw overflow" despite the first being more similar in terms of pronunciation.

I've just found [another page](http://www.dcs.shef.ac.uk/~sam/stringmetrics.html) which gives rather more options... in particular, the [Soundex](http://www.dcs.shef.ac.uk/~sam/stringmetrics.html#soundex) algorithm ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex)) may be closer to what you're after.

Comment: FYI, if you happen to be working with the data with SQL Server, it has a SOUNDEX() function.

Comment: Also, it should be noted that Soundex is an old algorithm intended mostly for English words. If you want a multi-lingual modern algorithm, consider using Metaphone. This article discusses the differences in greater detail: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1848528

Answer (score 27):

[Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: Here is a great example of how to write it, gotta love DotNetPerls.  http://www.dotnetperls.com/levenshtein

Answer (score 15):

Here is some code I have written for a project I am working on. I need to know the Similarity Ratio of the strings and the Similarity Ratio based on words of the strings.
This last one, I want to know both the Words Similarity Ratio of the smallest string(so if all words exist and match in the larger string the result will be 100%) and the Words Similarity Ratio of the larger string(which I call RealWordsRatio).
I use the Levenshtein algorithm to find the distance. The code is unoptimised, so far, but it works as expected. I hope you find it useful.

```
public static int Compute(string s, string t)
    {
        int n = s.Length;
        int m = t.Length;
        int[,] d = new int[n + 1, m + 1];

        // Step 1
        if (n == 0)
        {
            return m;
        }

        if (m == 0)
        {
            return n;
        }

        // Step 2
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; d[i, 0] = i++)
        {
        }

        for (int j = 0; j <= m; d[0, j] = j++)
        {
        }

        // Step 3
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            //Step 4
            for (int j = 1; j <= m; j++)
            {
                // Step 5
                int cost = (t[j - 1] == s[i - 1]) ? 0 : 1;

                // Step 6
                d[i, j] = Math.Min(
                    Math.Min(d[i - 1, j] + 1, d[i, j - 1] + 1),
                    d[i - 1, j - 1] + cost);
            }
        }
        // Step 7
        return d[n, m];
    }

double GetSimilarityRatio(String FullString1, String FullString2, out double WordsRatio, out double RealWordsRatio)
    {
        double theResult = 0;
        String[] Splitted1 = FullString1.Split(new char[]{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        String[] Splitted2 = FullString2.Split(new char[]{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        if (Splitted1.Length < Splitted2.Length)
        {
            String[] Temp = Splitted2;
            Splitted2 = Splitted1;
            Splitted1 = Temp;
        }
        int[,] theScores = new int[Splitted1.Length, Splitted2.Length];//Keep the best scores for each word.0 is the best, 1000 is the starting.
        int[] BestWord = new int[Splitted1.Length];//Index to the best word of Splitted2 for the Splitted1.

        for (int loop = 0; loop < Splitted1.Length; loop++) 
        {
            for (int loop1 = 0; loop1 < Splitted2.Length; loop1++) theScores[loop, loop1] = 1000;
            BestWord[loop] = -1;
        }
        int WordsMatched = 0;
        for (int loop = 0; loop < Splitted1.Length; loop++)
        {
            String String1 = Splitted1[loop];
            for (int loop1 = 0; loop1 < Splitted2.Length; loop1++)
            {
                String String2 = Splitted2[loop1];
                int LevenshteinDistance = Compute(String1, String2);
                theScores[loop, loop1] = LevenshteinDistance;
                if (BestWord[loop] == -1 || theScores[loop, BestWord[loop]] > LevenshteinDistance) BestWord[loop] = loop1;
            }
        }

        for (int loop = 0; loop < Splitted1.Length; loop++)
        {
            if (theScores[loop, BestWord[loop]] == 1000) continue;
            for (int loop1 = loop + 1; loop1 < Splitted1.Length; loop1++)
            {
                if (theScores[loop1, BestWord[loop1]] == 1000) continue;//the worst score available, so there are no more words left
                if (BestWord[loop] == BestWord[loop1])//2 words have the same best word
                {
                    //The first in order has the advantage of keeping the word in equality
                    if (theScores[loop, BestWord[loop]] <= theScores[loop1, BestWord[loop1]])
                    {
                        theScores[loop1, BestWord[loop1]] = 1000;
                        int CurrentBest = -1;
                        int CurrentScore = 1000;
                        for (int loop2 = 0; loop2 < Splitted2.Length; loop2++)
                        {
                            //Find next bestword
                            if (CurrentBest == -1 || CurrentScore > theScores[loop1, loop2])
                            {
                                CurrentBest = loop2;
                                CurrentScore = theScores[loop1, loop2];
                            }
                        }
                        BestWord[loop1] = CurrentBest;
                    }
                    else//the latter has a better score
                    {
                        theScores[loop, BestWord[loop]] = 1000;
                        int CurrentBest = -1;
                        int CurrentScore = 1000;
                        for (int loop2 = 0; loop2 < Splitted2.Length; loop2++)
                        {
                            //Find next bestword
                            if (CurrentBest == -1 || CurrentScore > theScores[loop, loop2])
                            {
                                CurrentBest = loop2;
                                CurrentScore = theScores[loop, loop2];
                            }
                        }
                        BestWord[loop] = CurrentBest;
                    }

                    loop = -1;
                    break;//recalculate all
                }
            }
        }
        for (int loop = 0; loop < Splitted1.Length; loop++)
        {
            if (theScores[loop, BestWord[loop]] == 1000) theResult += Splitted1[loop].Length;//All words without a score for best word are max failures
            else
            {
                theResult += theScores[loop, BestWord[loop]];
                if (theScores[loop, BestWord[loop]] == 0) WordsMatched++;
            }
        }
        int theLength = (FullString1.Replace(" ", "").Length > FullString2.Replace(" ", "").Length) ? FullString1.Replace(" ", "").Length : FullString2.Replace(" ", "").Length;
        if(theResult > theLength) theResult = theLength;
        theResult = (1 - (theResult / theLength)) * 100;
        WordsRatio = ((double)WordsMatched / (double)Splitted2.Length) * 100;
        RealWordsRatio = ((double)WordsMatched / (double)Splitted1.Length) * 100;
        return theResult;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a [Double Metaphone implementation in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/dmetaphone5.aspx) a while back.  You'll find it vastly superior to Soundex and the like.

Levenshtein distance has also been suggested, and it's a great algorithm for a lot of uses, but phonetic matching is not really what it does; it only seems that way sometimes because phonetically similar words are also usually spelled similarly.  I did an [analysis of various fuzzy matching algorithms](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/dmetaphone6.aspx) which you might also find useful.

Answer (score 4):

To deal with 'sound alikes' you may want to look into encoding using a phonetic algorithm like Double Metaphone or soundex. I don't know if computing Levenshtein distances on phonetic encoded strings would be beneficial or not, but might be a possibility. Alternately, you could use a heuristic like: convert each word in the string to its encoded form and remove any words that occur in both strings and replace them with a single representation before computing the Levenshtein distance.

Comment: The soundex algorithm is used by the medical community to warn about like sounding surnames. It is included in many standard libraries.

Comment: Metaphone is far superior to Soundex.

Answer (score 3):

You might look for string "distances", for example [the Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

Answer (score 3):

Perl module [Text::Phonetic](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text::Phonetic) has implementations of various algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

[Jeff Atwood wrote about looking for a similar solution](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001222.html) for determining the authorship of wiki posts which may help you narrow your search.

Answer (score 2):

If you're comparing values in a SQL database you can use the *SOUNDEX* function. If you query Google for SOUNDEX and C#, some people have written a similar function for that and VB.

Answer (score 1):

I have to recommend Soundex too, I have used it in the past to process misspelt city names. Here is a good link for usage: http://whitepapers.zdnet.com/abstract.aspx?docid=352953

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare phonetically, check out the Soundex and Metaphone algorithms: http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/algorithms/phonetic-string-comparison-with-soundex

Answer (score 1):

> Metaphone 3 is the third generation of the Metaphone algorithm. It
>   increases the accuracy of phonetic encoding from the 89% of Double
>   Metaphone to **98%**, as tested against a database of the most common
>   English words, and names and non-English words familiar in North
>   America. This produces an extremely reliable phonetic encoding for
>   American pronunciations.
>
> Metaphone 3 was designed and developed by Lawrence Philips, who
>   designed and developed the original Metaphone and Double Metaphone
>   algorithms.